# robotic arm controlled by mouse

Tags: robotic-arm, webots

I want to create a webot simulation for robotic arm. The entire arm should be controlled by the mouse. Is it possible to implement in webots?
I am trying simulation for this https://youtu.be/nz_tgDD8FNw

Comment: `controlled by the mouse` ... in which way? ... for example, is there a virtual joystick that can be grabbed by the mouse pointer?

Comment: I want to control the robotic arm using the mouse movements and clicks

Comment: what would you be clicking on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Webots there is the mouse node, with this you can capture the mouse events, but only the events that happen in the 3D window.

Link Reference Manual: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/mouse?tab-language=c

Example to get status of mouse: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xERoBf7CTFZpdXwBVb5UOtROao8F8Npd/view?usp=sharing

Video of example:
https://youtu.be/9QlW7n98oro

**Upgrade: january 19 2023**

Basic Arm V1 - Controlled by mouse and keyboard:
Video: https://youtu.be/CRfqlA7r0aA

Basic Arm V2 - Controlled by mouse and keyboard:
Video: https://youtu.be/ebUXBYJDIBE

Worlds Examples (Full: V1 & V2): https://github.com/DrakerDG/Webotz/tree/master/Basic_Arm

[image]

[image]

Evolution! Basic Arm V2

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the video is private.

Comment: Hi Draker, can you implement this simulation in webots? I will pay for it. Please let me know if it is doable for you

Comment: @OlivierMichel, my apologies, I forgot to change the video to public :/

Comment: @pavankumarsharma, yes I can. I have a project on one arm, maybe it's possible to add control using the mouse, but with some limitations and combined with the keyboard it would work similarly as you need

Comment: Great to hear that @DrakerDG. How can I contact you? I need the project before December 19th.

Comment: Can you make it using using mouse only for 3 degree of freedom?

Comment: Hi @pavankumarsharma, in Webots you can only use the mouse for 2 degrees of freedom. Because the left, middle and right buttons are assigned to specific functions in the 3D window

Comment: Hi @DrakerDG, can you add base wheel moment for robotic arm so that arm can be moved on floor. Please share world once done

Comment: Hi @pavankumarsharma, check this premiere video: https://youtu.be/ebUXBYJDIBE